# weird python indexing with CSV file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have simple phenomena that I'm having trouble understanding.
I load in a csv file

```
import csv
with open('Salaries.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
Salaries = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
Salaries = [row for row in Salaries]
```

I query it, and see 5 columns, for example

```
print Salaries[1][:]
['1985', 'BAL', 'AL', 'murraed02', '1472819']
```

If I look for the 5th index, which doesn't exist, it correctly throws an error:

```
print Salaries[1][5]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But if I run index 0:5 it doesn't throw an error:

```
print Salaries[1][0:5]
['1985', 'BAL', 'AL', 'murraed02', '1472819']
```

and weirdly, i see these results

```
print Salaries[1][0:1]
['1985']
print Salaries[1][0]
1985
print Salaries[1][1]
BAL
```

I know I'm missing something basic here, I'm just not getting it. help?

Comment: Python indexing is 0-based; the last index is *4*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running `print Salaries[1][0:5]` will print the list with a slice from the `0th` index up to and *not including* the `5th` index, so in math terms, the range is [0,4] or [0,5).

```
>>> mylist = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> mylist[0:4]
[0, 1, 2, 3] #4 is excluded, although it is the 4th index
```

In 2.7, you can arbitrarily slice up to any number and it will return the entire list if your slice range is longer than its length

```
>>> mylist[0:10231]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Something to note, this is typical of python in functions such as `range(x,y)` which is up until and not including `y`. This allows for calls such as `for i in range(0,len(mylist))` although many python users would suggest a different way of doing something.

Comment: omg, you are right. I lost my mind for a second there (mixing matlab and python in one sitting isn't a good idea).  thank you very much!

Comment: @user3186094 np glad I could help! Why don't the creators of these languages keep mutual standards :)